# Solving this equation for Taylor-series in Python

Tags: python, taylor-series

I'm a beginner at Python and I want to solve the following Taylor series:

```
g(x) = exp(-(x-3)**2)*sin(x)  # x=0  till range4
```

Could you help me please? I don't even know how to begin this task (except importing `sympy` and others).

Comment: http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/mpmath/calculus/approximation.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop to solve this

```
from math import exp, sin

g = [exp(-(x-3)**2)*sin(x) for x in range(0, 4)]
print(g)
```

the result will be a list in g, so you can find the x element by using g[x]

```
[0.0, 0.015412078693088957, 0.33451182923926226, 0.1411200080598672]
```

based on peter comment :

```
from sympy.mpmath import *

 def f(x):
     return exp(-(x-3)**2)*sin(x)

g = taylor(f, 0, 4)
```